# How to parse a web table in python that loads in browser but not in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, parsing, web

I would like to get a dataframe of the table from this website (tennis booking - https://clubspark.lta.org.uk/StJohnsParkLondon/Booking/BookByDate), but pd.read_html doesn't find any table and BeautifulSoup doesn't load (div class="booking-sheet clearfix") where all the data is contained.

I tried using selenium and requests but getting the same result, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That data is generated dynamically through Javascript.  You cannot use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` for this, nor can use you `pandas.read_html`.  You need to use `Selenium` to fetch it, and you need to use the `Selenium` APIs to troll through the objects in the DOM to extract your data.

Comment: So I need to imitate a browser via Selenium? I wa son the right path?

from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

?